# Has anyone ever used PreProcessControlMessage

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Has anyone ever used  `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.PreProcessControlMessage`? And what did you use it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a method on `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`, it just inherited it from the `System.Windows.Forms.Control` base class.

You'd only need to call it if you implement your own control and override the WndProc handling, it allows you to forward keyboard input to other controls out of order. If you look in Reflector you can see it's used for ActiveX and OLE container implementations.